# Unable to convert client value 'null' back into a server-side object

Tags: java, tapestry

This question is about `Tapestry` components issue.

I'm looking for a **solution of exactly this issue**, not any workaround or alternative ways, how to implement this interface.

1. Consider `ajaxformloop` element on the `Tapestry` form:

   `<tr t:type="ajaxformloop" t:id="items" source="getItems()" value="item">`

   `...`

   `</tr>`
2. `getItems()` method inside class returns synthetic combination (`List` interface) of persisted objects and not-yet-persisted newly added items (with `null` id inside them).
3. When submitting the form I receive this error:

   `Unable to convert client value 'null' back into a server-side object`

This error occurs **before** `onSuccessFromSave()` method (`save` is id of submit link).

I wonder, how can I manage such not-persisted objects with `ajaxformloop` to prevent such error. Actually, I want to save (in DB) these items inside my `onSucceccFrom...()` method.

What have I missed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I've missed custom `ValueEncoder` for my `ajaxformloop` container. The mentioned error produced by default `encoder` of this component.

Custom encoder should be set in such way:

`<tr t:type="ajaxformloop" t:id="items" source="getItems()" value="item" encoder="itemEncoder">`

where `itemEncoder` is `@Property` annotated field in java class:

```
@Property
private ValueEncoder<MyItem> itemEncoder = new ValueEncoder<MyItem>() {
    @Override
    public String toClient(MyItem value) {
        return value.id != null ? value.id.toString() : "";
    }

    @Override
    public MyItem toValue(String clientValue) {
        if (clientValue != null && !clientValue.isEmpty()) {
            Long id = Long.parseLong(clientValue);
            return (MyItem) session.get(MyItem.class, id);
        }
        return new MyItem();
    }
};
```